# how to concatenate python quantities?

Tags: numpy, scipy, units-of-measurement, quantities

I am working with the `quantities` module of python, and I want to concatenate two quantiy arrays. If I use `numpy.concatenate()`, I loose the unit from `quantities`. The `quantities` package itself does not provide a `.concatenate()` method for its arrays. How to avoid this?

Example:

```
import scipy as sp
import quantities as pq
a = [1,2,3]*pq.V
b = [4,5,6]*pq.V
sp.concatenate([a,b])
```

returns

```
array([1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6.]) * dimensionless
```

Comment: `np.concatenate` only knows about `numpy` arrays; it turns inputs into arrays, and returns an array.  If `quantities` doesn't provide that kind of function, then most likely you'll have to added the dimensions back on yourself.  That's probably the case with most `numpy` functions - they won't return as `quantities` object unless `quantities` provides a relevant method that it can deligate to.

Comment: this is what I would have expected, naively, and it is not the case. The return value of `sp.concatenate([a,b])` is, as you can see above, a `Quantity` of unit `dimensionless`. So I guess something in `numpy` removes the dimension because it doesn't handle it, and the object defaults to `dimensionless`. If that is possible, I thought maybe there is a way to prevent this from happening ...

Comment: It looks like `a` is a subclass of `ndarray`, and `np.concatenate` is preserving  subclass.  But it still doesn't 'know' enough to pass the dimensions through, or to resolve any conflicts.  Look at `np.ma.concatenate` to see how a subclass preserves attributes (e.g. the mask) during concatenation.  If `quantities` hasn't implemented that kind of action, you have to take care of it yourself.